# grep - blacklisting using a file

Tags: blacklist

New to using Grep. Basically I have two text files; blacklist.txt and many foo.txt in different directories. 
I started off using:

```
grep -vE "(insert|blacklist|items|here)" foo.txt > filtered_foo.txt
```

but my blacklist has grown exponentially and so I need to compare the two files instead.

In foo.txt there are four columns with columns 1,2,3 being unique. I want to delete rows where column 4 matches a string in my blacklist.

---

Sample of a foo.txt

```
A1 A2 A3 Bob  
B1 B2 B3 Anne  
C1 C2 C3 Henry  
D1 D2 D3 Ted
```

blacklist.txt

```
Anne  
Ted
```

---

Desired output: filtered_foo.txt

```
A1 A2 A3 Bob  
C1 C2 C3 Henry
```

---

I have tried different things in grep such as:

```
grep -vF "'cat blacklist.txt'" foo.txt > filtered_foo.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-f` option to get the patterns from a file.

```
grep -vF -f blacklist.txt foo.txt > filtered_foo.txt
```